# ScrollView background not shown

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi guys so I am making a log-in view in android and done something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:background="@drawable/manila">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#ffffff"
        android:backgroundTintMode="screen">

        <!--  Header Starts-->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@layout/login_header_gradient"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <!-- Logo Start-->

            <!-- Logo Ends -->

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="SSMIS"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_weight="0.10"
                android:textColor="#ffe8ebff"
                android:textSize="25px"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!--  Header Ends -->


        <!-- Footer Ends -->

        <!-- Login Form -->
        <!-- Login Form Ends -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

However, the background for scrollview is not shown. I think the relativelayout probably blocking it or whatsoever.

Your responses will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: try relativelayout bg as android:background="#00000000"

Comment: It cannot apply android:background on relativelayout. Android studio cannot detect it.

Comment: android:background="#ffffff" whats this then

Comment: android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent". I added this on relativelayout. And now its working. Thanks anyway.